# How to store childrens of the same model with entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have model Page:

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to have children pages there:

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Page> Childrens { get; set; }
```

What the best way to setup non required children items of same model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I went about it requires a few additional properties in your model (I'm using the virtual` keyword for my navigation properties because I required lazy loading):

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; } // Nullable int because your Parent is optional.

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; } // Optional Parent
    public virtual List<Page> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using a foreign key association, you can configure the relationship like so (this is my `Page` mapping):

```
// You may be configuring elsewhere, so might want to use `modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()` instead of `this`

this.HasMany(t => t.Children)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID);
```

Essentially, every child is aware of its parent, and as a result of the navigation properties, you can explore the relationship from both sides.